Prove isomorphism between naturals and their Boehm-Berarducci encoding
I can't figure out how to prove this isomorphism. Intuitively it holds, because the only way to combine the zero parameter and the successor parameter is to apply the successor parameter a few times to the zero parameter, but I can't see how to put that reasoning into Idris2 code.
Here's my attempt:
import Decidable.Equality
import Syntax.PreorderReasoning

infix 0 <->
record (<->) (a, b : Type) where
  constructor MkIso
  forwards  : a -> b
  backwards : b -> a
  inverseL  : (x : a) -> backwards (forwards x) === x
  inverseR  : (y : b) -> forwards (backwards y) === y

bbToNat : (forall s. (s -> s) -> s -> s) -> Nat
bbToNat f = f S Z

natToBb : Nat -> (forall s. (s -> s) -> s -> s)
natToBb 0 s z = z
natToBb (S k) s z = s (natToBb k s z)

data Bb = MkBb (forall s. (s -> s) -> s -> s)

unBb : Bb -> (forall s. (s -> s) -> s -> s)
unBb (MkBb x) = x

bbIsoNat : Bb <-> Nat
bbIsoNat = MkIso fwd bck iL iR where
  fwd : Bb -> Nat
  fwd (MkBb f) = f S Z
  bck : Nat -> Bb
  bck 0 = MkBb $ \s, z => z
  bck (S k) = MkBb $ \s, z => s (unBb (bck k) s z)
  iLHelper : DecEq a => (s : a -> a) -> (z : a) -> (x : Bb) -> bck (fwd x) === x
  iLHelper s z (MkBb f) with (decEq (f s z) z)
    -- commented-out code fails trying to unify `f s z = z` and `f s z = z` (mismatch between `a` and `Nat`)
    iLHelper s z (MkBb f) | (Yes prf) = ?todo -- Calc $
      -- |~ bck (f S Z)
      -- ~~ MkBb (\s, z => z) ...(cong bck prf)
      -- ~~ MkBb f ...(?rhs)
    iLHelper s z (MkBb f) | (No contra) = ?iLHelper_rhs_1
  iL : (x : Bb) -> bck (fwd x) === x
  iL (MkBb f) with (f S Z)
    iL (MkBb f) | 0 = ?iL_rhs_0
    iL (MkBb f) | (S k) = ?iL_rhs_1
  iR : (x : Nat) -> fwd (bck x) === x


